# Tensorflow Js biases quantities in a layer

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

in a simple neural network setting with tfjs, I was wondering why it adds this amount of biases per layer between `useBias: false` and `useBias: true` in a simple 3 hidden layer neural network:

```
_________________________________________________________________ tf-layers.esm.js:2776
Layer (type)                 Output shape              Param #   tf-layers.esm.js:2832
================================================================= tf-layers.esm.js:2776
dense_Dense1 (Dense)         [null,3]                  3         tf-layers.esm.js:2832
_________________________________________________________________ tf-layers.esm.js:2778
dense_Dense2 (Dense)         [null,3]                  9         tf-layers.esm.js:2832
_________________________________________________________________ tf-layers.esm.js:2778
dense_Dense3 (Dense)         [null,3]                  9         tf-layers.esm.js:2832
_________________________________________________________________ tf-layers.esm.js:2778
dense_Dense4 (Dense)         [null,1]                  4         tf-layers.esm.js:2832
================================================================= tf-layers.esm.js:2778
Total params: 25 tf-layers.esm.js:2783
Trainable params: 25 tf-layers.esm.js:2783
Non-trainable params: 0
```

```
________________________________________________________________ tf-layers.esm.js:2776
Layer (type)                 Output shape              Param #   tf-layers.esm.js:2832
================================================================= tf-layers.esm.js:2776
dense_Dense1 (Dense)         [null,3]                  6         tf-layers.esm.js:2832
_________________________________________________________________ tf-layers.esm.js:2778
dense_Dense2 (Dense)         [null,3]                  12        tf-layers.esm.js:2832
_________________________________________________________________ tf-layers.esm.js:2778
dense_Dense3 (Dense)         [null,3]                  12        tf-layers.esm.js:2832
_________________________________________________________________ tf-layers.esm.js:2778
dense_Dense4 (Dense)         [null,1]                  4         tf-layers.esm.js:2832
================================================================= tf-layers.esm.js:2778
Total params: 34 tf-layers.esm.js:2783
Trainable params: 34 tf-layers.esm.js:2783
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Seems that changing `useBias` to `true` attribute, it adds many biases in a same layer. In the end, isn't that inefficient, as many biases in a same layer will end up acting as just 1 bias?